# In distributed TensorFlow, is it possible to share the same queue across different workers?

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I want to have a filename queue shared across different workers on different machines, such that each machine can get a subset of files to train. I searched a lot, and it seems that only *variables* could be put on a PS task to be shared. Does anyone have any example? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to share the same queue across workers, by setting the optional `shared_name` argument when creating the queue. Just as with `tf.Variable` objects, you can place the queue on any device that can be accessed from different workers. For example:

```
with tf.device("/job:ps/task:0"):  # Place queue on parameter server.
  q = tf.FIFOQueue(..., shared_name="shared_queue")
```

A few notes:

- The value for `shared_name` must be unique to the particular queue that you are sharing. Unfortunately, the Python API does not currently use scoping or automatic name uniqification to make this easier, so you will have to ensure this manually.
- You do not need to place the queue on a parameter server. One possible configuration would be to set up an additional "input job" (e.g. `"/job:input"`) containing a set of tasks that perform pre-processing, and export a shared queue for the workers to use.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I use `"/job:input"` with a `tf.train.string_input_producer` and a `tf.train.shuffle_batch` (both with unique `shared_name`) it works only when `num_epochs` is set to `None`. When  `num_epochs != None` I get `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: RandomShuffleQueue 'shared_shuffle_batch' is closed.` error. How to configure "input job" or queus, so I can have workers reading from the same shared queue and the same epoch? (e.g. data-parallel between-graph replicated distributed training)