# Tensorflow shared queue in PS server with reader in workers

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am running a distributed Tensorflow program with large input files (150 MB per example).

I wish to have a shared input queue for file names in the **PS** in order for the workers to work on different examples.

I want the CPU of each worker to then read the shared input queue and generate data for the GPU to process.

The code below is only run by the workers:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    with tf.device('/job:ps/replica:0/task:0'):
        file_queue =tf.train.string_input_producer(file_paths, shared_name='train_queue')

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        input_tensors = model.input_fn(file_queue, ...)

    # sets variables to PS and ops default to GPU
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)):
        output_tensors = model.model_fn(input_tensors, ...)
```

However, the `Reader()` for `file_queue` (which is inside `model.input_fn()`) is being placed in the **PS** instead of in the workers' CPUs, as treid to specify using `tf.device()`.

This causes 150 MB messages being sent between the **PS** and the workers, which slows down training (I only notice this because google-cloud ml engine raises a warning when large messages are being sent).

Why is the `Reader()` not being placed on the workers' CPU? 
Is it mandatory for a queue and its reader to be on the same device?

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791372/distributed-tensorflow-device-placement-in-google-cloud-ml-engine) to my previous context which might provide more context.

Here is the code for `input_fn()`:

```
def input_fn(file_queue, ...):

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, example = reader.read(file_queue)

    image, ground_truth = my_decoder(example)
    image, ground_truth = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, ground_truth], ...)
    return image, ground_truth
```

The problem is `tf.TFRecordReader()` is being placed in the **PS**. All the other ops (decoder and batch) are correctly placed in the workers' CPUs.

Comment: The standard pattern in TensorFlow is for each individual worker to independently read all of the data, but each in a different random order. That means that any given step your learner is seeing a batch drawn roughly at uniform random from the full set (assuming you use `tf.train.shuffle_batch`. This removes single points of failure and reduces the traffic on the PS since the PS is often already I/O bound.

Comment: Also, consider checkng out the tf.data API (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)

Comment: I understand that, however, this is not a good solution for me, since computation on one single example is very expensive I cannot rely on training on a lot of batches to make sure each example has been roughly seen the same number of times.

Comment: Thank you,  but the Dataset API is only for Tensorflow 1.4 which unfortunately has not arrived yet to google-cloud ml engine.

Comment: My bad, it arrived December 11 2017 :)

Comment: I think it got rolled back last night...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161128/discussion-between-miguel-and-rhaertel80).

Comment: Let me find out if it's possible to have queues on PS, I'm thinking it might not be. That said, you could probably place the filename queue on the Master.

Comment: Thanks, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578441/in-distributed-tensorflow-is-it-possible-to-share-the-same-queue-across-differe)

Comment: oh, I thought you were using tf.estimator (I was thrown off by model.input_fn), but I think you're not. In that case you have much more flexibility.

Comment: I am not using tf.estimator(), I just use a similar structure because it is recommended for google cloud ml programs.

Comment: can you provide your input_fn? TensorFlow does sometimes collocate ops together.

Comment: I have added the code for `input_fn()` to the questions. Thanks for helping.